# Is  a word/letter?

Tags: words, unicode

Can "" (the Face with Tears of Joy emoji) be technically considered a word, from a linguistic point of view?

Obviously, emoji are different from "ordinary" words, but:

1. "" was the [Oxford *Word* of the Year 2015](https://languages.oup.com/word-of-the-year/2015/) (emphasis added)
2. "" has an [entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%9F%98%82) in Wiktionary
3. like Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, etc. letters (e.g. "A", "b"), emoji have Unicode code points (Unicode being "a standard for all the characters of all writing systems of the world" [[source](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode)])

Comment: 2 and 3 aren’t really much of an argument, since lots of non-letters have Unicode code points, and most Unicode code points have Wiktionary entries. All the box drawing glyphs and IPA diacritics aren’t letters, for example, but they have Wiktionary entries; and while control characters like carriage return or delete don’t have Wiktionary entries (how would you even get to them?), they do have Unicode code points, but definitely aren’t letters. Is it a word? Potentially. But how is it pronounced? ‘Word’ is notoriously undefinable, but having a pronunciation should be a basic requirement.

Comment: There are many ways of defining 'word'. I think to make your question meaningful you'd need to add a definition of word to it, or or specify a purpose for asking that might imply a definition. As it is I think it's unanswerable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There are Wikipedia articles on [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) with a redirect from [↵](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E2%86%B5&redirect=no), and one on the [delete character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) with a redirect from [⌦](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E2%8C%A6&redirect=no)

Comment: @Henry True, and you can probably look each of those names/symbols up on Wiktionary too; for other Unicode characters, however, you can look them up directly by inputting the Unicode value as the lookup form, which you can’t do with the control characters because you can’t have control characters in a URL.

Comment: Can you explain how you see "word/letter" as different?

Beyond that, isn't the emoji symbol set equivalent to all alphabets, hieroglyphics or what have you?

That's pretty-much to say, is the symbol part of a recognised set of symbols?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Emoji are probably different from "ordinary" words/letters; one of the reasons: they are never handwritten?

Comment: @Kellie Don't you think that's a mere co-incidence, particularly in the scope of linguistics? If there was a technical reason why it was impossible to write emoji by hand, that would be one thing. Isn't it true that in fact, they just happen never to be hand written, for no other reasons than that automation takes (a lot) less time and skill?

Comment: I find: the phrases "technically be considered a word" and "from a linguistic point of view" very problematical. Symbols like emojis are nothing new. Emoji is a word but is its symbol?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In corpus lingustics we deal with corpora containing emojis, e.g., twitter corpora or other corpora of *computer mediated communication*, and thus it is a legitimate question how to treat them.

Stand-alone emojis are treated as words (or [wordforms](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/40356/9781)) and they are even assigned a special part of speech named "Symbol" in Universal Dependencies (for an overview on part-of-speech tagsets, see [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12994/9781)).

Comment: I think it's sort of funny how English wound up partially going back to ideoglyphs because they accidentally re-imported them from Japan...

Comment: @nick012000 In English primarily only the 'emotional emoji' are used which are more similar to punctuation marks than ideograms. They express 'how' something was said rather than symbolizing a certain thing. Emoji that are symbolize specific things (e.g. ) aren't often used.

Comment: I recently started seeing  a lot on twitter, for "thread", and used exactly like a word.

Comment: Yea, and I guess if we have a much easier method to input emojis of word that we intend to say, emojis will be used as words as well. I've already seen people using emojis in place of nouns.

Comment: Well, on twitter (max 280), or any platform where there's a restriction in characters, there's use to replace long words by shorter characters. Some phones also offer to replace a word by a emoticon, which simplifies input.

Comment: @DavidMulder There are words that do that same kind of job too, e.g. *sadly* in: "Sadly, I can't come to your party". Would a sad emoji not be considered an ideogram for a concept similar to "sadly"?

Comment: @Araucaria-him But "sadly" is a spoken word, whilst saying something in a sad tone is about the tone and expression with which something is said. On chat we don't write "I sadly said 'fine'", we just write "fine ".

Comment: @nick012000 Long before emojis, English tech users were using emotica ( :) , :( , :/ , etc), created by an American. Those in turn were borrowed and expanded upon by forums, giving users an array of smileys. Emojis actually come from those smileys, so the route is far more complex than mere re-importation.